# Как каждый раз при выполнение скрипта увеличить переменную на 1 значение?

Tags: php

Нужно сделать так чтобы каждый раз при выполнение скрипта допустим переменная $result увеличивалась на 1, то есть в первый раз 0 второй 1 и так далее

Comment: без отдельного файла по моему ни как

Comment: а можно пример с файлом как это реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С файлом можно так.

```
<?php
//Выполняем скрипт, а затем
$str = htmlentities(file_get_contents("count.php")); // Читаем файл
echo $str; //Выводим что прочитали (нужно, чтобы там было число)
$fd = fopen("count.php", 'w') or die("не удалось создать файл");
$str++; //Прибавим единичку (ну конечно если в файле было число);
fwrite($fd, $str); //Записали
fclose($fd); //закрыли

?>
```

Comment: перед `$str++;`можно добавить строку `if(!is_numeric($str)) $str = 0;` чтобы избежать ошибок

Answer (score 2):

> *а можно пример с файлом как это реализовать?*

```
$file = 'all.txt';

$all = file_exists($file) ? (int) file_get_contents($file) : 0;
file_put_contents($file, ++$all);

echo $all;
```

Answer (score 1):

Элементарное использование сессии, не надо никаких дополнительных файлов.

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['result'])) $_SESSION['result'] = 0;

$_SESSION['result'] += 1;

$result = $_SESSION['result'];

echo $result;
```

Comment: Сессия рано или поздно будет разрушена

Comment: @ВладленВожжаев ну тогда сохранять значение в базе данных или в отдельном файле если нужно чтобы значение не имело срока жизни. В вопросе это не уточняется

Comment: @ВладленВожжаев хех, в ответе написано что без доп. файлов, но все-таки пришли  к этому варианту.

Comment: Сессия доступна только одному пользователю и это говорит о том, что у каждого пользователя будет свой счетчик. И всем он не будет виден. А с файлом как-раз, будет доступ у всех. Только нужно с блокировками поиграться.

Comment: @And да вы правы. я просто делал нечто похожее и на автомате написал ответ. в зависимости от того что будет счетчик считать море вариантов реализации. если он считает количество просмотров динамической страницы то такие данные надо сохранять в базе, если количество выполнений скрипта то в файле, если какая-то итерация то в сессиях. но этого мы не узнаем :)